# how to put flash (.swf) in a page?

Tags: html, flash

i'm planning to use a .swf file as a header. this won't work.

```
<img src="exactheader.swf" width="650" height="140" />
```

can you tell me how?

Comment: Has nothing to do with PHP. I don't know where you got the idea that putting flash in an img tag would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use **<embed>** tag to embed flash files to an html page :

```
<object width="650" height="140">
  <param name="movie" value="exactheader.swf">
  <embed src="exactheader.swf" width="650" height="140"> </embed>
</object>
```

**EDIT :** As Russ pointed, I just found the resource why we should use both object and embed tags [here](http://www.w3schools.com/flash/flash_inhtml.asp).

> In the code above there is both an
>    tag and an <object> tag. This
>   is because the  tag is
>   recognized by Internet Explorer, and
>   Netscape recognizes the <embed> tag
>   and ignores the <object> tag.

Comment: the embed tag has long since been deprecated, object should be used instead.

Comment: I have removed the downvote seeing as you have updated your answer.

Answer (score 8):

Try this instead:

```
<object width="650" height="140">
  <param name="movie" value="exactheader.swf">
  <embed src="exactheader.swf" width="650" height="140"></embed>
</object>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found swfobject the 'best' method for embedding flash in html. It handles, version checking, alternate content, etc. Spend a few minutes getting familiar with this easy to use api:
http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/